# I cannot use Quanterion values that i use with PyOpenGL.glRotatef in Unity

Tags: c#, python, unity-game-engine, pyopengl

i have values Quaternion(x,y,z,w)=(p0,p1,p2,p3)
in pyOpenGl

```
 norm=math.sqrt(program_dict['q0']*program_dict['q0'] + program_dict['q1']*program_dict['q1'] + program_dict['q2']*program_dict['q2'] + program_dict['q3']*program_dict['q3'])
    glPushMatrix()
    if (norm == 0):
        pass
    else:
        program_dict['q0'] = program_dict['q0'] / norm
        program_dict['q1'] = program_dict['q1'] / norm
        program_dict['q2'] = program_dict['q2'] / norm
        program_dict['q3'] = program_dict['q3'] / norm
        theta = ( math.acos(program_dict['q3'])*2)
        aNorm =  math.sqrt(program_dict['q1'] * program_dict['q1'] + program_dict['q2'] * program_dict['q2'] + program_dict['q0'] * program_dict['q0'])
        if (aNorm != 0):
            glRotatef(theta*180.0/math.pi, program_dict['q2']/aNorm, -program_dict['q0']/aNorm, program_dict['q1']/aNorm)
        else:
            glRotatef(theta*180.0/math.pi, program_dict['q2'], -program_dict['q0'], program_dict['q1'])
```

I normalize the data first (btw data comes from an prototype device so it must be normalised)
How can i use this in c# Unity and rotate an object? I dont know how Unity units work...

Comment: What do you mean by "I cannot use Quaternion values"? Unity's Transform has localRotation and rotation properties which are Quaternions. What problems do you encounter when using them?

Comment: I know that they are quaternions but it doesnt work ! It rotates it but these are very small rotations :( i believe numbers are really tiny for unity. which unit should i use for quaternions in Unity ? Works fine with opengl

Comment: glRotatef uses an axis-angle representation. Quaternions are not that. You can't directly put the values from one into the other and expect it to work. You can however create a valid Quaternion from an axis and angle representation using https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.AngleAxis.html Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: thank you Bart !! Quaternion.AngleAxis solved my problem !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The confusion here is between an axis-angle representation and a quaternion. The glRotatef you are using uses the former, while the `rotation` and `localRotation` of Unity's `Transform` are the latter.

You can however convert between the two. [`Quaternion.AngleAxis(float angle, Vector3 axis)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.AngleAxis.html) does exactly that. It takes the axis-angle representation and converts it to the corresponding Quaternion. This you can then feed into `localRotation` for example.